# Hide <rich:popupPanel> on escape key press

Tags: jquery, jsf, richfaces

I have a `<rich:popupPanel>` which I want to close on press of Escape key. The popup panel has an 'onclick' event, but no key events associated with it.
I tried using the keyup event (jQuery) but nothing seems working in this case. Please note that I can only use Richfaces 3.3.x

Comment: Do you mean [`rich:modalPanel`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html)? I think [`rich:popupPanel`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_2_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Panels.html#sect-Component_Reference-Panels-richpopupPanel) is a component of Richfaces 4... Are you sure you got the Richfaces version right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Richfaces `<rich:hotKey/>` component to hide the popup panel thus:

```
<rich:hotKey selector="#mypanel" key="escape" handler="#{rich:component('mypanel')}.hide()"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I'm restricted to use only RF 3.3 version.

Comment: @TeenaStanley, don't see a problem, `<rich:hotKey/>` is available in 3.3

Comment: not sure why JSF is unable to find out the tag. I got this exception: <rich:hotKey> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: hotKey

Comment: @TeenaStanley that's weird. [Here's the richfaces doc on 3.3's hotkey](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/devguide/html/rich_hotKey.html). Try to check your richfaces distribution for the class `org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlHotKey`

Comment: I'm sorry just found out that the version is upgraded to RF 4.0.0.Final. The hotkey is not included in this version. Just found out this post by Illya: https://community.jboss.org/thread/163751

Comment: I tried the hotkey plug in of jQuery as well. I can hide/close everything in the <rich:popupPanel> except the panel. I have a form inside the popupPanel which contains all the elements displayed in the popup. I am able to close this form(which is <h:form>)

Comment: following this on jboss community forum for Richfaces from now on. Thanks kolossus and elias for your valuable suggestions.    https://community.jboss.org/message/799810#799810